# PdfStamp of IText 5.4.4 causes exception when calling Close()

Tags: itext, pdfstamper

The simple code below causes exception "Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1" AS LONG AS the pdf producer is "Mac OSX 10.8.5 Quartz PDFCOntext" 1.4 (Arcobat 5.x). Any other pdf works without err.

```
 PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(fullInputPath);
 using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(fullOutputPath, FileMode.Create))
 {
     using (stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, fs))
     {
     }  <= got err here!
  }
```

Please help!

Thank you in advance

Comment: As the issue occurs with but one pdf, this very pdf is needed for analysing the problem. A first guess: the error message sounds like a xml parsing error message. Thus, i assume the issue is related to the root metadata of the pdf.

Comment: Can you reproduce the issue with iText `5.5.9`? Because *if* it is a bug, it will *not* be solved in `5.4.4` but in `5.5.10`. But as @mkl already hints, it is very likely to be an issue with a malformed pdf file.

Comment: Thank you very much guys for quick reply! I will have a try.

Comment: Had a try. the 5.9.9 WORKs! thank you guys!